# Honeybee Hangover

Tags: no-computers, probability

A drunken honeybee lands on a completely random hexagon of a large triangular section (depicted below) of its hive, and then every second afterwards, takes a step to a completely random adjacent hexagon. How long on average will it take for the honeybee to escape this region?
[image]

This is my own transformative result of an existing probability problem. Hint: The solution (for this given case) will be an integer!

Comment: I worked out some small triangles by hand, and it seems to indicate the answer for side length 17 is rot13(gjraglbar), but I'm failing to see why such pattern arises...

Comment: cant think of a solution without a computer :)

Comment: I had a submitted edit rejected to change *'depicted below'* to *'depicted below for n=17'*. It actually makes a difference to whether the assertion *"Hint: The solution will be an integer!"* is only being claimed for n=17 as depicted, or in general. (cc: @VoldemortsWrath)

Comment: @smci -- The question has already been (correctly) answered, so it's clearly answerable without the edit. Therefore, it's really not needed.

Comment: @VoldemortsWrath: you're misunderstanding me. I said the claim hidden down the bottom of the question *"The solution will be an integer!"* for all n is stronger than just claiming that for n=17 case; which seemed counterintuitive at first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Let $n$ be the size of the triangle and $(a,b,c)$ the barycentric coordinates of a given hexagon within that triangle, such that $a+b+c = n+2$. I claim that the average escape time $E$ when starting from that hexagon is $\frac {3abc} {n+2}$ (1).
>  Indeed, we have the system of equations $E(a,b,c) = 1 + \frac{E(a+1,b-1,c) + E(a,b+1,c-1) + E(a-1,b,c+1) + E(a-1,b+1,c) + E(a,b-1,c+1) + E(a+1,b,c-1)} {6}$
>  
>  and it is straight forward to check that the $E$ given by (1) satisfies these equations and the boundary conditions which are $E(a,b,c) = 0$ if $a=0 \vee b=0 \vee c=0$.

> It remains to average over starting points: $\langle E \rangle = \frac {2} {17\times 18} \sum_{a+b+c = 19} \frac {3abc} {19}$ The sum can be recognized as up to prefactors the binomial coefficient $\begin{pmatrix}21 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$ yielding $\langle E \rangle = \frac {2} {17\times 18} \times \frac {3} {19} \times\begin{pmatrix}21 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} = 21$

> To get some intuition for the formula
>  $\begin{pmatrix}N+2n \\ 2n+1 \end{pmatrix} = \sum_{i_0,\ldots,i_n \ge 1, i_0+\ldots+i_n = N+n} i_0 \cdots i_n$ recall that the binomial coefficient on the l.h.s. can be interpreted as the volume (number of cannon balls) in an 2n+1-dimensional pyramid shaped pile of cannon balls with N cannon balls along each edge. This can be shown by a routine stars-and-bars argument using barycentric coordinates.
>  
>  [image] Source: wikipedia public domain

> Leaving the subtleties of discretization to one side let us project the $2n+1$-simplex (which has $2n+2$ barycentric coordinates) to the $n$-simplex (which has $n+1$ barycentric coordinates) simply by pairing coordinates and summing pairs. We can now ask what are the shape and volume of the subset of the large simplex that gets mapped to a single point in the small simplex?
>  One can work out that it must be a (hyper) cuboid, but maybe it's easier to just look at a picture:
>  
>  [image] Source: wikipedia CC BY-SA 4.0 Tomruen

Comment: Well done! rot13(Gur ovg nobhg gur ovabzvny pbrssvpvrag vf arj gb zr; jurer qbrf gung sbezhyn pbzr sebz? (V whfg qvq fbzr nytroen gb svther bhg gur fhz) Nyfb, ner lbh noyr gb zbgvingr jurer gung pryy-jvfr sbezhyn lbh irevsvrq pnzr sebz?)

Comment: @Feryll rot13 V tbg obgu ol rkgencbyngvat gur 1Q pnfr. Gur 1Q pnfr pna or fbyirq ol unaq sbe fznyy rqtr yratguf naq gur sbezhyn pna or thrffrq gura. V qba'g unir nal tbbq vaghvgvba jul vg fubhyq or guvf sbezhyn. Er gur ovabzvny pbrssvpvrag: Gur 1Q pnfr vf fbeg bs vaghvgvir: Guvax bs gur pnaaba onyy grgenurqeba juvpu vf glcvpnyyl hfrq nf ivfhnyvfngvba bs gur fhzzngvba sbezhyn sbe gevnatyr ahzoref. Abj gnxr vg naq qb abg onfr vg ba n snpr ohg ba bar rqtr. Gura vafcrpgvat gur ynlref lbh jvyy svaq erpgnatyrf bs svkrq pvephzsrerapr naq fhesnpr nernf 1ka 2k(a-1) rgp.

Comment: V frr. Nf sbe pbzvat hc jvgu gur sbezhyn va gur svefg cynpr, vs lbh gnxr abgvpr bs ebgngvbany naq ersyrpgvba flzzrgel, gura nal nytroenvp sbezhyn jbhyq unir gb or n pbzovangvba bs ryrzragnel flzzrgevp cbylabzvnyf va gur onelpragevp pbbeqvangrf. Gung vzzrqvngryl cbvagf lbh gb n irel erfgevpgrq cbby bs fhfcrpgf :)

Comment: @Feryll rot13 Jnfa'g vg gur pnfr gung rirel flzzrgevp cbylabzvny pna or rkcerffrq nf n cbylabzvny va ryrzragnel flzzrgevp cbylabzvnyf? Be nz V zvfhaqrefgnaqvat fbzrguvat? Btw. I added a (very informal) sketch of how to obtain the summation formula.

Comment: Lrf, ps shaqnzragny gurberz bs flzzrgevp cbylabzvnyf